# Do i need to drop table after i use merge? Error when running the select top 1000 query on table i merged

Tags: sql, sql-server

I altered on of my stored procedures to use Merge, so that i could insert entrys if they did not exist or update them if i did.

After running the following script i can view my table, Do i need to drop the merge table or end it or something?

When i run a select top 1000 query it just hang's.

Is there something in the below SQL that would cause this error?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Suppliers].[ProductPropertyInsert]
@ProductId int
,@PropertyId int
,@PropertyValue nvarchar(50)

AS

BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE Suppliers.ProductProperties AS target
    USING (SELECT @ProductId, @PropertyId) AS source (ProdId, PropId)
    ON (target.ProductId = source.ProdId)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET PropertyValue = @PropertyValue
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN    
        INSERT (ProductId, PropertyId, PropertyValue)
        VALUES (@ProductId, @PropertyId, @PropertyValue);

    INSERT INTO Suppliers.ProductProperties (ProductId, PropertyId, PropertyValue)
    VALUES(@ProductId, @PropertyId, @PropertyValue)

END
```

Comment: What do you mean by hangs? What does `sp_who2` show? Is it being blocked by another spid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used MERGE, but I'd like to know how it works too.  It looks like the parameters should be incorporated into the MERGE.  Following [Example A from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), it looks like you should be able to write:

```
MERGE Suppliers.ProductProperties AS target
USING (SELECT @ProductId, @PropertyId, @PropertyValue) AS source (ProdId, PropId, PropVal)
ON (target.ProductId = source.ProdId)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET PropertyValue = source.PropVal
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN    
    INSERT (ProductId, PropertyId, PropertyValue)
    VALUES (source.ProdId, source.PropId, source.PropVal);
```

I'm guessing the extra INSERT was left over from your first pass?  It's not part of the MERGE.

```
INSERT INTO Suppliers.ProductProperties (ProductId, PropertyId, PropertyValue)
VALUES(@ProductId, @PropertyId, @PropertyValue)
```

So I would omit the second INSERT.  Still, I don't see any reason why your code should lock up the Suppliers.ProductProperties table.  This should give you a count of the records:

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Suppliers.ProductProperties

See if this helps.

Comment: Thanks i did forget that second insert, and you corrections make a lot more sense. Thanks iv gotten this to work perfectly.